# Difference in FCC and US Census data

Tags: kml, census

I am comparing 2 lists of census data for the state of IL.

One from the [FCC.GOV](https://www.fcc.gov/general/census-blocks-state)
where I download all the census tracts in CSV format and the data looks like this

```
state,county,cnamelong,tract,tractname,block,tractcode,blockcode
17,001,Adams County,000100,1,1000,17001000100,170010001001000
17,001,Adams County,000100,1,1001,17001000100,170010001001001
17,001,Adams County,000100,1,1002,17001000100,170010001001002
...
```

The 2nd comes from [CENSUS.GOV](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/2013/geo/kml-cartographic-boundary-files.html) which comes as a KML file. A sample of the data looks like this

```
<th>GEOID</th>
<td>170119649001</td>
```

I need to cross reference the data, but there is a problem.
The CSV tractcode is 11 digits, and the FCC geocode is 12 digits.
The first 11 digits are the same. 
[This site](https://www.policymap.com/2012/08/tips-on-fips-a-quick-guide-to-geographic-place-codes-part-iii/) says the last number is the "block group" number. I don't see where that comes from. I need it in the CSV.

My questions are:

- What data is apparent for me to cross reference these 2 data sources?
- Where can I find the "block group" number where I can append it to the tractcode in the CSV for use of cross-reference?
- Can I just use the first 12 digits of the "blockcode" in the CSV to compare?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Please check out our short [tour] which emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  In any event if these questions are about open data then they may be better asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the first 12 digits of that "blockcode" field. The last four digits is called the "block code" and the first digit of those last 4 is the "block group number"

```
state,county,cnamelong,tract,tractname,block,tractcode,blockcode
17,001,Adams County,000100,1,1000,17001000100,17001000100>>>1<<<000
17,001,Adams County,000100,1,1001,17001000100,17001000100>>>1<<<001
17,001,Adams County,000100,1,1002,17001000100,17001000100>>>1<<<002
...
```

http://proximityone.com/geo_blocks.htm

Comment: that's exactly what I need to know, thanks!